# Intermittent "Unable to connect remote server" on Azure hosted sitecore 10.2 site

Tags: sitecore-client, azure

We have a `Sitecore 10.2` site hosted on `Azure App services`. Very often site is getting down with the blank page throwing error `Unable to connect remote server`. If we refresh multiple times, then site will be up but it will keep on coming same error till we restart the service.

This behaviour has been observed over QA and Pre-prod environments also.

Any possible way to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot of workaround on this issue, we finally resolved the issue with the suggestion from Sitecore Support Team.

Basically this was a JSS issue where it is unable to render the page.The issue occurs in cases when the JSS application works in the Integrated Mode.

As per the Sitecore Article https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000535

Setting the value of the "**ConnectFailureNodeRestart**" configuration to "**true**" on all of your Sitecore instances, resolved my issue.

By default, the property is defined in the following file: `App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.config`.
You can also set the value by creating a configuration patch file in the `\App_Config\Include\zzz` folder.

Note: It is always a best practise to have all default configuration changes through patch config.